# Cmd + PgUp/Down shortcut to navigate through terminal tabs

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

is it possible to make <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd> shortcut performing switch tab in Terminal?

At the moment I can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> shortcuts to do the thing, but this is horrible for me. I'm using external USB Keyboard and Karabiner, if that may help somehow.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:
The answer now reassigns *Scroll to Top/Bottom* to <kbd>⌥⌘PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>⌥⌘PageDown</kbd>.
This leaves *Show Previous/Next Tab* free to take over <kbd>⌘PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>⌘PageDown</kbd>.

---

Assuming your OS X runs in English, you can use this one-liner:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Scroll to Top' '~@\Uf72c' 'Scroll to Bottom' '~@\Uf72d' 'Show Previous Tab' '@\Uf72c' 'Show Next Tab' '@\Uf72d'
```

If your OS X runs in a language other than English, modify the command to resemble the exact menu item text for your language.

Comment: seen this answer somewhere else with slight variations, but it doesn't appear to work - could you please confirm that this should still work today?

Comment: @Chris Turns out the answer broke due to conflicting shortcuts. I have fixed the answer and can confirm it works for me now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts` to configure custom shortcuts for anything available in the menus of an application.

Just choose the application from the list or `Other...` to select an application not in the list (or leave it at `All Applications` for every application), type in the exact menu text and supply a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Even though you are generally right about configuring shortcuts this way - it appears impossible to utilize `Page Up` or `Page Down` (or `End`, `Home`) this way, which is what the question was about specifically.

Comment: I was aware what the OP wanted. The only thing I was not aware of was that Page Up/Down was not possible as I saw that I used these keys as shortcuts on my computer somewhere. It may have been in a 3rd party application then where I used it.

Comment: To be honest - there is no good reason in my opinion why it can't be used there and I would expect to be able to configure it exactly as you suggest, but for some unknown reason Apple doesn't allow us to do that.